# Add prebuild event to UWP WAP Packaging project VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

We have created a new UWP packaging project in Visual Studio 2022 and would like to add a simple prebuild event to copy a file. However right clicking on the project and selecting Properties the build events tab is grayed out and no events can be specified.
We have noticed the other C sharp projects support adding these events. As the packaging project is at the top level we need to add the event there. Anyone know how to do it if the UI doesn't allow us to do this
Thanks